# Android UIAutomator long click on device

Tags: java, android, testing, android-uiautomator

I would like to perform long click on specified point with specified time. Unfortunately there is no method like long click in class: [UiDevice](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html)
I probably could write own method, something like this:

```
private void longClick(int x, int y, long time) {
    android.graphics.Point point = new android.graphics.Point(x, y);
    android.graphics.Point[] points = new android.graphics.Point[2];
    points[0] = point;
    points[1] = point;
    getUiDevice().swipe(points, time / 5); // according to documentation, each step lasts 5ms
}
```

or use reflection and invoke longTap:

```
private void longClick(int x, int y) {
    Field mUiAutomationBridgeField = getUiDevice().getClass().getDeclaredField("mUiAutomationBridge");
    mUiAutomationBridgeField.setAccessible(true);
    Object mUiAutomationBridge = mUiAutomationBridgeField.get(getUiDevice());
    Field mInteractionControllerField = mUiAutomationBridge.getClass().getDeclaredField("mInteractionController");
    mInteractionControllerField.setAccessible(true);
    Object mInteractionController = mInteractionControllerField.get(mUiAutomationBridge);
    Method longTap = mInteractionController.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("longTap", int.class, int.class);
    longTap.setAccessible(true);
    longTap.invoke(mInteractionController, x, y);
}
```

However it's not satisfied solution, any idea how to do it better way? Why do they miss such method?

Comment: Check out the below link

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156959/issue-with-long-click-using-instrumentation-class-in-uiautomator-for-4-3-android>?

Comment: Please go through the below link

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156959/issue-with-long-click-using-instrumentation-class-in-uiautomator-for-4-3-android>?``

Answer (score 6):

```
getUiDevice().getInstance().swipe(x, y, x, y, 400);
```

Start point and end point are same.
Then you can simulate uiDevice longclick.

Answer (score 2):

I think swipe a UiObject is better.

```
yourUiObject.swipeRight(int steps);
yourUiObject.swipeLeft(int steps);
yourUiObject.swipeDown(int steps);
yourUiObject.swipeUp(int steps);
```

Anyone of them works great for me.
Notice that the doc says one step takes about 5ms, but I found it's not true.

Comment: I don't have any object. I just would like to perform long click on x,y

Comment: this swipe call works when I tried on Android 4.3. wish that UiObject.longClick() will actually do long click