# Issue with Long click using instrumentation class in uiautomator for 4.3 android version

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I tried to performing long click on screen using the Motion Event class and instrumentation class.

This class seems to work fine for 4.2 and below devices but when I tried to implement the same on the 4.3 devices I'm facing the following exception

Could any one please help me out in resolving this problem

Thanks in Advance

The method which I used to perform long click event is

```
private void longClickOnScreen(float x, float y) {
            try {
                long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
                MotionEvent event2 = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
                inst.sendPointerSync(event);
                Thread.sleep(750);
                inst.sendPointerSync(event2);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 



 java.lang.RuntimeException: This method can not be called from the main application thread
            at android.app.Instrumentation.validateNotAppThread(Instrumentation.java:1651)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(Instrumentation.java:933)
            at com.kpt.adaptxt.uitest.event.EventHandler.longClickOnScreen(EventHandler.java:84)
            at com.kpt.adaptxt.uitest.event.EventHandler.longClick(EventHandler.java:149)
            at com.kpt.adaptxt.uitest.testsuite.UiautomationTestsuite.testLongpressEvent(UiautomationTes
    tsuite.java:24)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java
    :160)
            at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:9
    6)
            at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:91)
            at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
After lots of research I solved the above problem by using following piece of code

private void longClickOnScreen(int x, int y) {
        try {
            long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            final MotionEvent eventDown = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime,
                    eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
            eventDown.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);
            final MotionEvent eventUp = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
            eventUp.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);
            Thread task = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                private Handler handler;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Looper.prepare();
                    handler = new Handler();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            inst.sendPointerSync(eventDown);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(750);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            inst.sendPointerSync(eventUp);
                        }
                    });
                    Looper.loop();
                }
            });
            task.start();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```